# Can I put a bib file somewhere on the tex tree so its found by biber or bibtex like a package is found by pdflatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

To elaborate a bit more, let's say I have a `tex` file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references-global.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{myref1,myref2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In its folder, there is no `references-global.bib` file, so naturally I have an error when biber is called:

```
ERROR - Cannot find 'references-global.bib'!
```

My question therefore is: can I place this `references-global.bib` in a location where it would be found by biber regardless of where my `tex` file is located (much like a package or so)

Comment: Would it not work simply to write the full path to `references-global.bib`? E.g. `\addbibresource{C:\\User\blah\references-global.bib}`?

Comment: I believe so. But I'd have to always write it, and it would change from PC to PC. I was looking for a solution where I could have a global bibliography, perhaps synced with git, dropbox or something, such that I could have an extensive bibliography resource, easily accessed throughout several machines!